# how to pass a string as a command to a for loop in a bash script

Tags: git, bash, shell, ubuntu, grep

I am working on a bash script(I am very new to do this) that will loop through all my files to be committed using GIT. However when I pass the command to the for loop I get the following error:
fatal: ambiguous argument '|': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
the command that I am passing to the loop works fine in the terminal. I have the following script:

I run the script as follow: BYPASS_LEGACY=yes ./check_debug_code.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$BYPASS_LEGACY" == "yes" ]
then
gitCommand="git diff --cached --name-only | egrep -v'(folder1|folder2|([A-Za-z])\w+.*X)'" 
else
gitCommand="git diff --cached --name-only"
fi

DEBUG_CODE_FOUND="no"

for i in "$($gitCommand)"
do 
r=$(grep -nrH --color=always 'dump\|print_r\|console.log(\|var_dump(\|echo\|print(' $i) 
if [ "$r" != "" ];then
echo "$r"
DEBUG_CODE_FOUND="yes"
fi
done
if [ "$DEBUG_CODE_FOUND" == "yes" ];then
   echo "======================please remove the Debug to be able to commit.========================"
exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Any help will be very helpful.

thank you.

Comment: What you want is either `eval` or `bash -c`.

Comment: thank you it worked using eval.

Comment: A word of precaution for future - when assembling commands like this, pay extra attention to any variables you use, as they can mess up your script pretty badly. (Example - statements like `eval "git something $variable"`).

Comment: Please start indenting and learning bash coding style.  This is not fun to read.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either `eval` or `bash -c`. – rr